# How to track the percentage of the page loading?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, loading, tracking

We need some way to track the percentage of the page loading.

For example, on the page in different parts of the code to place some 3 elements that would have signaled the percentage of the page loading. Ie the first element has been loaded 10 times, the second 10 and the third only 5.

Thus it would be possible to determine that between loading the second and third elements we have an issue that must be fixed to increase the loading percentage of the total page.

Is there any way to create such tracking in Google Analytics?

Comment: Unless you're talking about showing a percentage load of a second page you're loading, I don't think it's possible to show loading of the very first page. Since the page isn't loaded yet, you have no place to render a progress bar to. If you're talking about later pages, you can probably hook something up to a progress event of an ajax call.

Comment: first search on web. you will definiatly find way. after that if you fail in implementing then post question

Comment: Depends upon the element types that you are loading. If they are images then you can attach the onload event to them and then do what you need to do. You can also look at the developers toolbar (every browser has one now - press the F12 key). In Chrome you can use either the Network, Timeline, Profiles and/or Audits for the information that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there exist `metrics` for this already. I made something similar when working with google's [`core reporting api`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=site_speed&jump=ga_pageloadtime) so will provide some examples i used from it.

**ga:pageLoadTime**

*Total Page Load Time is the amount of time (in milliseconds) it takes for pages from the sample set to load, from initiation of the pageview (e.g. click on a page link) to load completion in the browser.*

**ga:domInteractiveTime**

*The time the browser takes (in milliseconds) to parse the document (DOMInteractive), including the network time from the user's location to your server. At this time, the user can interact with the Document Object Model even though it is not fully loaded.*

**ga:domContentLoadedTime**

*The time the browser takes (in milliseconds) to parse the document and execute deferred and parser-inserted scripts (DOMContentLoaded), including the network time from the user's location to your server. Parsing of the document is finished, the Document Object Model is ready, but referenced style sheets, images, and subframes may not be finished loading. This event is often the starting point for javascript framework execution, e.g., JQuery's onready() callback, etc.*